# Почему при создании в Visual Studio проекта Google Test в проекте отсутствует точка входа main()?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gtest

У меня есть следующий вопрос.

Когда я создаю в `Visual Studio` проект `Google Test`, я не могу найти в проекте следующий код:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Тем не менее, при запуске тесты каким-то волшебным образом выполняются. И даже генерируется `exe`.

Скажите, пожалуйста, как это происходит?

Comment: https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/e3f0319d89f4cbf32993de595d984183b1a9fc57/googletest/src/gtest_main.cc#L49

Comment: @user7860670, получается, мне нельзя определять свою точку входа?

Comment: https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/e3f0319d89f4cbf32993de595d984183b1a9fc57/googletest/docs/primer.md#writing-the-main-function

Comment: Большое вам спасибо за помощь!